# How do i confirm the action delete(POST) in my controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, controller, viewmodel

I have a ViewModel and I would like to make a fonctionnal delete(GET) and deleteConfirmed(POST) so i can delete what ever data is stored in my DB

I don’t know and would like to know what step to take to complete the deleteConfirmed. There is normally auto-generated code but it’s not what I need.

here is my ViewModel

```
using System;
using ExploFormsDB.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ExploFormsDB.ViewModels
{
    public class WorkShiftDetailViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int WorkShiftId { get; set; }
        public int? HoleId { get; set; }
        public string HoleName { get; set; }
        public int SurveyLocationId { get; set; }
        public int SupplierId { get; set; }
        public int ZoneId { get; set; }
        public string SurveyLocation1 { get; set; }
        public string  SupplierName { get; set; }
        public string ZoneName { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDay { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDay { get; set; }

        public ICollection<WorkerViewModel> WorkShiftEmployees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

Here is my Controller, i have included the Create to help have a better understanding. GET: Delete seems to be working correctly, i am having trouble with the Post. any help what so ever will do. if the question as been answered already please send me a link. I'm pretty new to c# and core and completly new to ViewModels

---

````
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(WorkShiftDetailViewModel workShiftDetailViewModel)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                WorkShift ws = new WorkShift();
                ws.StartDay = workShiftDetailViewModel.StartDay;
                ws.EndDay = workShiftDetailViewModel.EndDay;
                ws.SupplierId = workShiftDetailViewModel.SupplierId;
                ws.SurveyLocationId = 1;
                ws.ZoneId = workShiftDetailViewModel.ZoneId;
                ws.HoleId = workShiftDetailViewModel.HoleId;
                _context.Add(ws);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                foreach (WorkerViewModel member in workShiftDetailViewModel.WorkShiftEmployees)
                {
                    if (member.isDeleted == false) {
                        WorkShiftTeam emp = new WorkShiftTeam();
                        emp.EmployeeId = member.EmployeeId;
                        emp.RoleId = member.RoleId;
                        emp.WorkShiftId = ws.WorkShiftId;
                        _context.Add(emp);
                    }
                }
                HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("wsId", ws.WorkShiftId);

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(CreateSharedView));
            }

            return View(workShiftDetailViewModel);
        }

         public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            List<WorkerViewModel> Workers = new List<WorkerViewModel>();
            WorkShift ws = _context.WorkShift.Include(w => w.WorkShiftTeam).SingleOrDefault(x => x.WorkShiftId == id);
            WorkShiftDetailViewModel detail = new WorkShiftDetailViewModel();
            detail.HoleName = ws.HoleId == null ? "N/A" : _context.Hole.Find(ws.HoleId).HoleName;
            detail.StartDay = ws.StartDay;
            detail.EndDay = ws.EndDay;
            detail.ZoneName = _context.Zone.Find(ws.ZoneId).ZoneName;
            detail.SurveyLocation1 = _context.SurveyLocation.Find(ws.SurveyLocationId).SurveyLocation1;
            detail.SupplierName = _context.Supplier.Find(ws.SupplierId).SupplierName;
            detail.WorkShiftId = ws.WorkShiftId;

            int order = 0;

            var rolelist = new SelectList(_context.Role, "RoleId", "Role1");

            var empsWithFullName = from e in _context.Employee.Where(a => a.IsActive)
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       ID = e.EmployeeId,
                                       FullName = e.LastName + ", " + e.FirstName
                                   };
            var empList = new SelectList(empsWithFullName, "ID", "FullName");

            foreach (WorkShiftTeam member in ws.WorkShiftTeam.OrderBy(a => a.EmployeeId))
            {
                Workers.Add(new WorkerViewModel() { EmployeeId = member.EmployeeId, RoleId = member.RoleId, Index = order, Roles = rolelist, Employees = empList });
                order++;
            }
            detail.WorkShiftEmployees = Workers;

            return View(detail);
        }

        // POST: WorkShiftDetailViewModels/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            //??
        } ```
````

Comment: You forgot to say what the problem was.

Comment: You should use POST for any actions that changes the state of your system GET is used for retrieve information.

Comment: Is your problem how to write the code of the DeleteConfirmed method? The forum is to solve problems encountered in the code, not to write code to implement a function.Please show the code you have tried, and what you delete eventually is up to  your demand. You could take aside time to learn the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?view=aspnetcore-3.0#update-the-delete-page)

Answer (score 0):

Why you created an extra method for delete action as HttpGet? (that occurred conflict)

change it to:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetById(int? id) { ... }
```

and just one delete method with this definition

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id) { ... }
```

Comment: the method was auto generated and don't seem to cause any issue, could you explain further your reasoning ? thank you

Comment: You have 2 method with one name and same input parameter. due to rename action name in run-time by call metadata [ActionName("Delete")]

Comment: please insert your client side code that call action with post method to find exact problem